# How to remove last url location hash using javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Am using bootstrap modal on my site, everything a modal is open it will add url has using the modal element id and a data i passed.

My problem is how do i remove the last added hash when a button is clicked just like when browser back button is click window will navigate back removing last hash.

How do i remove last url location has accordingly using javascript, i want every time a button is clicked the last hash from the list of url hash will be removed.

```
function ensureHash(newHash){
    var lochash = location.hash;
    if(lochash || lochash != ""){newHash = lochash + "&" + newHash;}
    if (window.location.hash) {
        return window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.lastIndexOf(window.location.hash)) + newHash;
    }
    return window.location.hash + newHash;
}
window.location.href = ensureHash("modalElementId=modalAction");
```

`https://example.com/app?#mElem1=mAcct1&#mElem2=mAcct2&#mElem4=mAcct5`

I tried doing this but it doesn't work well

```
function ensureRemoveHash(){
 var gethash = location.hash;
 gethash = gethash.slice(0, gethash.lastIndexOf('&'));
 return gethash;
}
window.location.href = ensureRemoveHash();
```

Comment: Why are you adding it back in then? `newHash = **lochash +** "&" + newHash;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var str = "https://example.com/app?#mElem1=mAcct1&#mElem2=mAcct2&#mElem4=mAcct5"
function dropHash(str) {
  if (str.indexOf("#") ==-1) return str;
  var arr = str.split("#");
  arr.pop();
  return arr.join("#");
}

console.log(str);
str = dropHash(str)
console.log(str);
str = dropHash(str)
console.log(str);
str = dropHash(str)
console.log(str);
```

Or do you just have the button replace the hash?

```js
var url = new URL("https://example.com/app")
console.log(url);
url.hash="mElem2=mAcct2"
console.log(url);
url.hash="mElem3=mAcct3"
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Yes but how to do you drop the last hash from the url if only one left?

Comment: See update. I did not console.log the last change. Also I added another suggestion